# What does "have an extra arm" mean? Is she talking the danger in the sea?

Tags: meaning

She talked about going to the beach and said (time stamp https://youtu.be/OnjzKmc6sCI?t=41)

> if you'd like to have an extra arm or lose an arm

What does that mean, is she talking the danger in the sea?

Comment: It doesn't have any special or unobvious meaning. 

For reasons I don't understand, she is talking literally about having an extra arm. I have no idea what she means.

Comment: @ColinFine when she said "lose an arm", is she talking literally about losing an arm? Is she talking the danger in the sea?

Comment: No, I don't think she can be talking about danger in the sea, because she says "or an extra arm". I repeat, I have no idea what she means. Maybe it's something Canadian.

Comment: Bizarre. I have no idea what she means. I’m thinking about it being very cold (your arm drops off?) or being attacked by something, but nothing fits.

Answer (score 2):

The [following](https://www.livescience.com/34571-lake-ontario.html) hints at a likely explanation for the video’s apparently bizarre claim that swimming in Lake Ontario may cause you to “have an extra arm or lose an arm”.

> Lake Ontario may be the most polluted out of the five Great Lakes. All
>   of the other lakes flow into it, giving it their pollution. It also
>   receives runoff from farms and businesses around it...

It seems it has a reputation for being *polluted* and dangerous for swimming, although various [other sources](http://www.waterkeeper.ca/blog/five-lake-ontario-beaches-to-explore-this-weekend) dismiss that claim, citing water tests that show pollution levels are acceptable. The Canadian woman’s choice of words is a joke based on the **urban myth** that pollutants cause mutations such as extra/missing limbs.

It is still a very odd thing to say and odd way of saying it - even the urban myth says children will be *born* with mutations rather than acquire them after a swim. But that nevertheless seems to be the explanation for this usage.

Comment: As I said, "Maybe it's something Canadian". Thank you for finding this explanation, which seems likely to be right.

Comment: Yep. Who’d have thought it, eh? (That’s my bad attempt at a Canadian accent in writing!)